# MySQL query comparing values to previous rows' values

Tags: mysql, row, lag

I've been searching but have been unable to find a solution to this--I know it's do-able but I just don't have the ninja SQL skills I need (yet)....

I'm looking for a solution to this issue: I have a 2 tables related to stock market data.  The first is a simple list of stock symbols with an ID and stock ticker symbol (ID,SYMBOL).  The second table contains historical price data for each of the stocks.  (ID, DATE, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME).

I'm trying to figure out how to query for stocks that have the most recent CLOSE price that is greater than their CLOSE price 5 trading-days ago.  I can't just do date math because the stocks don't trade every day (no trading on weekends & holidays, as well as some stocks may not trade on a normal trading day).  Thus, I just need to compare the CLOSE price from most recent row and the 5th row proceeding it for each symbol.

I have sample tables and data here: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fe76/2

```
CREATE TABLE `STOCKS` (
  `ID` int,
  `SYMBOL` varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO `STOCKS` (`ID`,`SYMBOL`)
VALUES
  (1, 'AA'),
  (2, 'ADT'),
  (3, 'AEO'),
  (4, 'AFA');

CREATE TABLE `PRICES` (
    `ID` int,
    `DATE` date,
    `OPEN` decimal(6,2),
    `HIGH` decimal(6,2),
    `LOW` decimal(6,2),
    `CLOSE` decimal(6,2),
    `VOLUME` bigint
  );

INSERT INTO `PRICES` (`ID`,`DATE`,`OPEN`,`HIGH`,`LOW`,`CLOSE`,`VOLUME`) VALUES
(1, '2014-11-06',   16.37,  16.42,  16.15,  16.37,  14200400),
(1, '2014-11-05',   16.68,  16.69,  16.17,  16.26,  18198200),
(1, '2014-11-04',   16.85,  16.87,  16.43,  16.56,  13182800),
(1, '2014-11-03',   16.78,  17.03,  16.65,  16.93,  15938500),
(1, '2014-10-31',   16.43,  16.76,  16.24,  16.76,  18618300),
(1, '2014-10-30',   16.17,  16.36,  15.83,  16.22,  17854400),
(1, '2014-10-29',   16.58,  16.70,  16.05,  16.27,  31173000),
(1, '2014-10-28',   16.5,   16.65,  16.41,  16.60,  12305900),
(1, '2014-10-27',   16.56,  16.57,  16.31,  16.38,  15452900),
(1, '2014-10-24',   16.33,  16.57,  16.22,  16.55,  12840200),

(2, '2014-11-06',   35.9,   36.12,  35.75,  36.07,  1018100),
(2, '2014-11-05',   35.68,  35.99,  35.37,  35.96,  1101500),
(2, '2014-11-04',   35.13,  35.69,  35.02,  35.49,  819100),
(2, '2014-11-03',   35.81,  35.99,  35.27,  35.32,  1304500),
(2, '2014-10-31',   35.79,  35.86,  35.46,  35.84,  1319400),
(2, '2014-10-30',   34.7,   35.34,  34.66,  35.19,  1201800),
(2, '2014-10-29',   35.06,  35.56,  34.5,   34.92,  1359000),
(2, '2014-10-28',   34.32,  35.17,  34.15,  35.07,  1301800),
(2, '2014-10-27',   34.2,   34.2,   33.66,  34.1,   662600),
(2, '2014-10-24',   34.02,  34.54,  33.95,  34.5,   750600),

(3, '2014-11-06',   13.27,  13.92,  13.25,  13.82,  6518000),
(3, '2014-11-05',   12.95,  13.27,  12.74,  13.22,  8716700),
(3, '2014-11-04',   12.85,  12.94,  12.65,  12.89,  4541200),
(3, '2014-11-03',   12.91,  13.12,  12.73,  12.89,  4299100),
(3, '2014-10-31',   13.2,   13.23,  12.83,  12.87,  7274700),
(3, '2014-10-30',   12.83,  12.91,  12.68,  12.86,  4444300),
(3, '2014-10-29',   13.02,  13.20,  12.79,  12.91,  2974900),
(3, '2014-10-28',   12.87,  13.10,  12.52,  13.04,  7365600),
(3, '2014-10-27',   12.84,  13.00,  12.67,  12.92,  6647900),
(3, '2014-10-24',   13.26,  13.29,  12.60,  12.92,  12803300),

(4, '2014-11-06',   24.59,  24.59,  24.49,  24.55,  20400),
(4, '2014-11-05',   24.81,  24.9,   24.81,  24.88,  11800),
(4, '2014-11-04',   24.87,  24.88,  24.76,  24.88,  10600),
(4, '2014-11-03',   24.85,  24.88,  24.76,  24.81,  18100),
(4, '2014-10-31',   24.82,  24.85,  24.77,  24.78,  8100),
(4, '2014-10-30',   24.83,  24.87,  24.74,  24.79,  13900),
(4, '2014-10-29',   24.86,  24.86,  24.78,  24.81,  5500),
(4, '2014-10-28',   24.85,  24.85,  24.80,  24.84,  10600),
(4, '2014-10-27',   24.68,  24.85,  24.68,  24.85,  7700),
(4, '2014-10-24',   24.67,  24.82,  24.59,  24.82,  9300);
```

Pseudo code for the query would be something like this:
"Find symbols whos most recent closing prices is greater than the closing price 5 trading-days earlier"

The query I'd like to create should result in the following:

```
Date        Symbol   Close   Close(-5)
2014-11-06  AA       16.37   16.22
2014-11-06  ADT      36.07   35.19
2014-11-06  AEO      13.82   12.86
```

(the symbol 'AFA' would not match as it's recent close is 24.55 and 5 rows prior it was 24.75)

Comment: So you want to find a) the most recent price for each stock but b) only hang onto those whose price is higher than 5 days ago? BUt if what if there wasn't a price 5 days agao !?!

Comment: And seeing as symbols are unique and (presumably) unchanging, why would you store the id instead of the symbol!?!

Comment: I guess I understand why ADT and AEO are in the result, but not AA

Comment: To your first question... I probably wasn't clear enough in my original description. I want to hang on to those who's price is higher than 5 trading days ago, not 5 calendar days ago. Trading days are simply defined as the 5 previous rows from the PRICE table.

Comment: Symbol names do occasionally change, thus storing an id.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the price 5 days ago using a correlated subquery.  In fact, you can get the most recent price the same way.  So, this  might be the right path:

```
  select s.*,
         (select p.close
          from prices p
          where p.id = s.id
          order by date desc
          limit 1
         ) as Close,
         (select p.close
          from prices p
          where p.id = s.id and p.date <= date(now()) - interval 5 day
          order by date desc
          limit 1
         ) as Close_5
  from stocks s
  having Close > Close_5;
```

Comment: Gordon - thank you for this answer. Unfortunately date-based offset won't work in every case as some days such as weekends and holidays are not trading days. The sub query needs to select the 5th-most-recent closing price--that's the part that has me stumped :)

Comment: @paul I think you should amend your question accordingly

Comment: @Paul . . . I think you should ask another question and be clearer about the issues you are facing with dates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In the orig. question it says that "date math" wont work as the dates have gaps.  So I'd say this isn't a "date issue". As I'm unable to figure this out perhaps I'm not asking the correct question; any suggestion on how to make this more clear? Trying to boil-it-down... I need to select stock symbols where the most recent closing price is greater than the closing price 5-ROWS prior (the rows are sorted by date but the dates in each row are not consecutive days--there are "gaps" in the dates).  Any guidance on how to make the question more clear is greatly appreciated, thanks! :)