# Finding local minima, maxima and interval samples with MySQL 5.6/7

Tags: mysql, graph

Single table time series of data points (eg power or temperature readings).
How can a sample be efficiently selected for the generation of graphs which inludes all local minima, maxima and a nth sampling of other data using MySQL 5.x?

Other SQL solutions use:

1. Self joins, select values where prev.val < val and next.val < val for maxima (> for minima), using join on id-1 and id+1. *This assumes a sequential unique ID*
2. Similar logic using LEAD and LAG functions to select the previous and next records
3. Modulo math on ID to select a sample, which misses maxima / minima unless selcted by chance

MySQL 5.x - no self joins on temp tables, no LEAD and LAG functions, and this data does not have sequential IDs - therefore the need to use temp tables to re-assign IDs sequentially.

Sample Data:

```
id      datetime            val
194038  2018-07-01 11:30:20 102
194050  2018-07-01 11:31:40 86
194054  2018-07-01 11:31:50 101
194065  2018-07-01 11:33:51 98
194075  2018-07-01 11:35:50 97
194085  2018-07-01 11:37:50 99
194095  2018-07-01 11:39:50 114
194100  2018-07-01 11:40:40 158
194105  2018-07-01 11:40:50 116
194115  2018-07-01 11:41:00 139
194124  2018-07-01 11:41:30 110
194128  2018-07-01 11:41:40 121
194132  2018-07-01 11:41:50 168
194143  2018-07-01 11:43:51 135
194153  2018-07-01 11:45:50 128
194163  2018-07-01 11:47:00 95
194173  2018-07-01 11:49:00 69
194186  2018-07-01 11:51:00 64
194194  2018-07-01 11:51:31 16
194198  2018-07-01 11:51:41 45
194209  2018-07-01 11:53:40 60
194219  2018-07-01 11:55:40 59
194229  2018-07-01 11:57:40 68
194246  2018-07-01 11:59:40 67
```

A solution using temporary tables works, but is horribly ineficient: (see inline comments)

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp2;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp3;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp4;

# Get data of interest into tmp with sequential ID
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)
SELECT datetime, val 
FROM log
ORDER BY datetime;

# Make copies of tmp (MySql can't self join on temporary tables)
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp2
SELECT * FROM tmp;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp3
SELECT * FROM tmp;

SELECT A.datetime, A.val
FROM tmp A, tmp2 P, tmp3 N
# Join next and previous records (emulates LAG() and LEAD())
WHERE A.id = P.id + 1
AND A.id = N.id - 1
AND (
        (
        # select local maxima
        A.val >= P.val
        AND A.val >= N.val
        )
    OR (
        # select local minima
        A.val <= P.val
        AND A.val <= N.val
        )
    # select a sampling of other records
    # mod value changed by calling code depending on zoom level of graph     
    OR A.id mod 4 = 0
    )
ORDER BY A.datetime
```

Expected and actual result:

```
datetime            val
2018-07-01 11:31:40 86
2018-07-01 11:31:50 101
2018-07-01 11:33:51 98
2018-07-01 11:35:50 97
2018-07-01 11:40:40 158
2018-07-01 11:40:50 116
2018-07-01 11:41:00 139
2018-07-01 11:41:30 110
2018-07-01 11:41:40 121
2018-07-01 11:41:50 168
2018-07-01 11:47:00 95
2018-07-01 11:51:31 16
2018-07-01 11:51:41 45
2018-07-01 11:53:40 60
2018-07-01 11:55:40 59
2018-07-01 11:57:40 68
```

Is there a better way to do this (or optimise this)?

Comment: I don't understand the selection criteria

Comment: Sorry - not sure what you don't understand - from a table with an arbitary date range (could be years - sample is illistrative) I just want to select enough data points to draw a reasonable graph. Which needs to include every nth record (eg A.id mod 4 = 0 would limit it to records divisible by 4) but must include all the peaks and troughs so that the outlying highs and lows are visible without resorting to polynomial fitting functions etc. Does this clarify?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I think I would handle this kind of analysis in my application code

Comment: Yes it would be far simpler to do that however the UI that consumes this data is a dash board that is remotely connected to the data (either via MySQL natively or via a webservice) so its not feasible to return the volume of data that underpins the much smaller set required to draw some lines on the screen. So thats why I'm trying to filter it down to points of interest plus a few for smoothing on the DB side, before it gets served.

Comment: So peaks and troughs are simply changes in direction, right?

Comment: Yes. Though this runs the risk of returning "jittery" data, but I can't think of a better way without resorting to a lot of math embedded in stored procedures.

Comment: BTW clarified in edit - the self join limitation only applies to temporary tables which are used to regenerate temporary IDs that are sequential and can be used for the ID+1 and ID-1 joins which emulate the Lead and Lag functions.

Comment: Why can't you do this in the webservice code?

Comment: Web services code would perhaps be the best location eventually. At present, I'm yet to write a proper web service for it (still on that learning curve), and this project has "evolved" from using a local mysql instance to using AWS RDS, with intent to wrap it in a web service eventually. Regardless, would be interested to know if there's a better way to do this at the SQL layer, as its really just a complex form of data filtering. Seems it would use a lot more resources to ship a raw qury result (could be 000,000's of records) to be then crunched in code before delivering the 500 required.

Comment: You can get the local mins and maxes via correlated subqueries. The additional points can be sampled via user defined variables. How performant such query would be - I don't know.

Comment: What do you mean by correlated subquery? I'm not familiar with the concept sorry.

Comment: Well, a little google search can do miracles in learning new concepts. See the following SO question for a starter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811482/mysql-query-comparing-values-to-previous-rows-values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178575/discussion-between-brendanmcl-and-shadow).